# Removing Index Pandas list from Combobox

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, combobox

Good Afternoon Everyone,

I would to create a Combobox taking the data from the csv, hence extracting them with pandas. Here the script:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import StringVar, ttk
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana",12)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)


def extractionFile(link,link2):
    df1=pd.read_csv(link, delim_whitespace=True,dtype=str,names= ['a','b','c','d','e'])
    df1['e']=pd.read_csv(link2,usecols=[0], names=['f'],header= None)
    return (df1)


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__ (self, *args, **kargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kargs)
        container= tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top",fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames= {}
        frame=StartPage(container,self)
        self.frames[StartPage]=frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__ (self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label=tk.Label(self, text= "StartPage", font= LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=20,padx=20)


        value2=StringVar()
        button2=ttk.Combobox(self,textvariable=value2)
        button2['value']= (extractionFile(r'/Users/Documents/Python/CFG UBLOX.txt',r'/Users/Documents/Python/CFG UBLOX_desc.txt')['c'])
        button2.pack(side='left')

        value3=StringVar()
        button3=ttk.Combobox(self,textvariable=value3)
        button3['value']= (extractionFile(r'/Users/Documents/Python/CFG UBLOX.txt',r'/Users/Documents/Python/CFG UBLOX_desc.txt')['d'])

        button3.pack(side='left')



run=App()
run.geometry("900x600")
run.mainloop()
```

As you could see, on the Combobox there are the data of the selected column + the index. How can I remove index from the Combobox ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you get an item from a `DataFrame` it returns a `Series`, if you want a list instead then just call `.tolist()` on the output `Series`.

Comment: It's working!! Thanks a lot!